# How to get org-time-stamp to return timestamp rather than inserting?

Tags: org-mode, time-date

I am writing a function that includes the formatted timestamp that is produced by the prompt from `org-time-stamp`. However, calling the function cause it to insert the timestamp into the buffer.

Is there any other similar function which produces the same calendar prompt as `org-time-stamp` that I can utilize for my function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such function: `org-time-stamp` is "sui generis".

The best thing to do is to define a new function that calls `org-time-stamp` in the context of a temporary buffer and then returns the string that is inserted into that buffer:

```el
(defun my/org-time-stamp-string ()
   (with-temp-buffer
      (org-mode)
      (org-time-stamp nil nil)
      (buffer-substring (point-min) (point-max))))
```

Then you can call it like this:

```el
(setq ts (my/org-time-stamp-string))
```

to store the string in `ts` and then do whatever you want with it.

For a different example of the same technique, see [another recent answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/68996/14825) of mine.